# How does a server determine what version of TLS to use?

Tags: ssl, https

I understand now there's a negotiation between the client and the server...
But what determines how a **server** chooses the TLS version it will use when responding to a https request? How might it, for example, restrict connections to a minimum version of TLS? Also, is there a relationship between the security certificate used by a server and the version of TLS that the server uses? I was reading through some AWS docs and it seemed to suggest this.

Total newb here; apologize if this is the wrong from for asking. I don't mind a link to go and read, as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what determines how a server chooses the TLS version it will use when responding to a https request?

In the TLS handshake the client announces the best version it can do to the server. If the server supports protocol versions which are equal or less to the clients version it will reply with the best of these. If the server supports none of these the handshake will fail. If the server replies with a version which is not supported by the client the handshake will fail too.

> Also, is there a relationship between the security certificate used by a server and the version of TLS that the server uses?

There is almost no relationship between the TLS protocol version and the certificate used. There is a small difference between the long obsolete SSLv3 and the TLS 1.x versions of the protocol in that only the TLS 1.x support extensions. An important extension is `server_name` ([SNI - Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)) where the client specifies the domain it wants to reach. In cases of multiple certificates on the same IP address the server can thus pick the appropriate one.

Comment: OK - thanks! I guess I'll accept this answer, but still confused by "If the server supports protocol versions..." I guess you both mean TLS is a low-enough level protocol that one would not normally need to manually configure it in a http server...

Comment: @yen: correct, you usually don't explicitly configure the TLS protocol versions in the server. At most you restrict that it should not use specific obsolete versions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a TLS protocol Handshake negociation expert so here is a ''rough'' answer (Experts, correct me if I am wrong)
* I am only talking about TLS version here. Not the cyphers.

Scenario 1:
You client will try the highest version of TLS it can. Let say you client support 1.1(OLD) and 1.2. Then, the server will connect you using the highest version possible. Hoping it will be 1.2.

Scenario 2:
Your client support 1.2 or later and your server is a old and not updated machine that only know about 1.1.

Scenario 3: 
Same as 2, but the other way around. Connection won't work either.

You client won't be able to negotiate the connection. It will stop there.

Scenario 4:
Your client support version 1.1 and 1.2 as well as the server, but let say the server admin configured (let say Apache HTTPD) to force connection only using 1.2, then you client will use 1.2.

Also, there is TLS 1.3.... But that would be the same mind set.(idea)

Comment: I suggest you disable TLS 1.1 on all of your servers and make sure you use a modern browser or client.

Comment: You can also test you publis sites with a tool such as: https://www.ssllabs.com/     It is a good start and you can get info on how fix what is not up to date of not correctly configured.

Comment: My question is actually about this statement: _"Then, the server will connect you using the highest version possible"_ ... it knows to do this how? Where is all this configured? Sorry if this is a very stupid question...

Comment: Actually, I think this will answer your question. It has a graphic and is pretty easy to understand IMO. Hope this help answering your question: https://www.ssl.com/article/ssl-tls-handshake-overview/

Comment: Also, here is the RFC of TLS 1.2 with all of the ''scientific'' details --- https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246